# Is there a sanskrit translation of the Pali tipitaka online?

Tags: pali-canon, reference-request, books

I see the ambatta sutta [in pali](http://tipitaka.pbworks.com/w/page/22282003/Amba%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADhasutta) and [in English](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/dob/dob-03tx.htm), but my personal preference is to read it in Sanskrit. Is there a sanskrit translation available online (say in a scanned book at archive.org)?

Answer (score 5):

Very few of the early Buddhist texts survive in Sanskrit translation. Also the Sanskrit translations were made relatively late, perhaps the 4th or 5th century CE and they had frequently been substantially changed by this point. For example the *Samaññaphala Sutta* does survive in Sanskrit, but it is a very different text (and as far as I know, only available in a PhD thesis).

There is a comprehensive list of parallels in different languages on a website called [Sutta Central](https://suttacentral.net/). In the case of the [Ambaṭṭa Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/dn3) there are only fragments of a Sanskrit text extant. Most of these are only in [manuscript form.](http://idp.bl.uk/database/oo_scroll_h.a4d?uid=9054871317;recnum=102375;index=2)

The Pāḷi Canon (in the Burmese, 6th Council Edition) is available in Devanārarī and a number of other non-Roman scripts via [tipitaka.org](http://www.tipitaka.org/)

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the Sutta Central website! Its such a relief to be able to see pAlI in devanAgarI, and the hindI rendering.

Comment: The hindI rendering uses more sanskrit-like words, which makes it so much easier to relate to.

Comment: If you wanted a Devanāgarī rendering rather than a Sanskrit translation you should have said. For reading online: http://www.tipitaka.org/deva/

Comment: No, I indeed wanted Sanskrit translation, but now settle for pAli and hindI in devanAgarI in its absence. (Thanks for the new link too!)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Link: http://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Buddhist-Texts/BT-index.htm

The Pāḷi Dhammapada is the second collection in the same Nikāya. Although many of the texts in the Suttanipāta are found to have parallels in Sanskrit (and also in Chinese and Tibetan translations), there is no sign that this collection as such ever existed outside of the Theravāda tradition.